# How to open local html file in default browser

Tags: android, browser, android-intent

I can open my local html file with android browser by following way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(webPageUri, "text/html");
intent.setClassName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

And it works. But I would like to open my local html file in **default browser** without specifing:

```
intent.setClassName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
```

Is there a way to to that?

**Edit:**

If I remove setClassName as you suggest, it opens in HtmlViewer (it is not a **default browser**).
And if I do it like that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(webPageUri);
startActivity(intent);
```

I get: ActivityNotFoundException

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the intent.setClassName line? It should be safe because then if there is a default browser then the system will launch it, if not the system will pop up a list of available browsers/html viewers and let the user choose which one to use.

Comment: Maybe irrelavant to your question, but to be more precise you should add a proper category like this "intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);"

Comment: just don't specify it. i don't understand how this is a problem

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(webPageUri, "text/html");
startActivity(intent);
```

This will give the user a list of installed browsers to choose from. If there is only one browser, then that's the one that will be launched.

Comment: It doesn't work, if I remove setClassName it opens in HtmlViewer.
And if I do this:

      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      intent.setData(webPageUri);
      startActivity(intent);

I get ActivityNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `setClassName()` line and you are set to go.

This will launch the default browser if it is the only browser in the phone. If there are more than one, the user will have to select one.

Comment: It doesn't work, if I remove setClassName it opens in HtmlViewer.
And if I do this:

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(webPageUri);
startActivity(intent);

I get ActivityNotFoundException